# Graphic problem with spell animations with Elder Scrolls: Oblivion

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I have this problem in my Elder Scrolls 4 game (see video below):

Do you see the magic animation? It's like the magic had lag, instead of needing a second to finish, with this problem it needs a lot more time.

This is the second time that this has happened to me, in the Steam version. I think there is a problem with the cinematic, because the first time it happened before I finished the main quest, so the final cinematic of the game took over 20 minutes to complete.

Because of that, I started the game again. This time I finish the main quest, and the DLC content. Now I *was* playing with mods, but this problem appears yet again.

Could anyone guess why is this happening? I try with previous saves but the same problem happens.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a longstanding bug with the game that's unrelated to what mods you have set up. According to the [UESP Wiki](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion_talk:Glitches#Animation_slowdown_.28Abomb_bug.29), the bug is called the "A-bomb" or "Animation bomb" bug, and occurs after several hundred hours of playtime. The exact amount of playtime appears to be about 250 to 300 hours on PC, and 450 to 500 hours on console. This bug is in **every single copy of Oblivion** and has been in the game, supposedly, since launch. Anyone who has played a character for hundreds of hours **will** run into this issue. Further, reloading a save to a point in time *prior* to being afflicted with this bug will still result in the bug occurring later on.

I've tracked this issue back to [this thread](http://www.gamesas.com/slow-frozen-doors-fire-spell-etc-animations-thread-t35545.html) from 2011, which includes a variety of messaging about this bug being reported to Bethesda, and receiving replies that Bethesda is both aware of the bug, and unable to fix it. Several users mused about a possible savefile hex editor fix, some of which were usable and some of which were not.

In the end, clever minds persevered, and there are a couple fixes that are most easily doable on PC. As further explained in the [UESP Wiki](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion_talk:Glitches#Animation_slowdown_.28Abomb_bug.29), here are the listed solutions:

##### Solution 1 - Savefile hex editing (Ideally by installing a tool to do it for you)

You only need to edit one byte in your savefile to repair this problem. There are tools available that were created purely for this service. Here are the two most popular:

1. ["Animation Fixer"](https://www.nexusmods.com/oblivion/mods/5127) - This one is run-and-forget, unless you run into the problem again, in which case you can just run this tool again. When you download it, a textfile is included that properly explains how to use the tool. It's pretty simple.
2. ["Wrye Bash"](https://www.nexusmods.com/oblivion/mods/22368) - Includes many tools to solve a wide variety of problems with the game, and thus is more complicated to navigate mainly because there are a lot more tools at your disposal. On opening, find the "Saves" tab, right click your savefile, and select "Repair A-Bomb".

These should also work for console, however you may need to re-sign your savefiles for your particular console, or else your console may reject the file as an unsigned file for security/corruption/anti-tampering purposes.

Performing the save edit manually using a hex editing tool is under-documented and poorly explained all across the web, so my biggest recommendation for you is to use one of the two linked tools.

##### Solution 2 - Edit a .ini file (PC Only)

In your Oblivion folder (this is typically in `Documents/My Games/Oblivion`), find the `Oblivion.ini` file, and change the following line:

```
fAnimationMult=1.0000
```

To:

```
fAnimationMult=2.0000
```

By name alone, this *seems* to just increase animation speed, however it allegedly refreshes all animations, such as the magic heal animation, to operate as they should.

Comment: Do you know what happens if you change the fAnimationMult to something not as fast as double? like 1.0001?

Comment: @Malady Unfortunately, without testing personally, I couldn't say. None of the settings are documented by Bethesda, and some of them aren't even documented by others. I imagine it'd be an interesting setting to toy with, though. [This guide](https://stepmodifications.org/wiki/Guide:Oblivion_INI/General#fAnimationMult) lists `fAnimationMult` as having a wide range of any decimal number (i.e. `0.0001` is an acceptable setting). So, assuming this does control the animation speed multiplier, then it would simply set that multiplier to a decimal instead of a whole number.